# ASP.NET 2.0: Why can my class access the Session object when run on my local machine, but not when I deploy it to the server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, asp.net-2.0

I have a custom MembershipProvider that I'm using in an ASP.NET 2.0 application. Inside of the class that extends membership provider, I have a function called `AttemptLogin()` that sets session variables if the user is valid. Inside that function, are a number of session variable assignments similar to the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] = "12345";
```

`AttemptLogin()` is being called by the `Application_BeginRequest` function in global.asax. This code works fine when I open it in visual studio, and then run it in the built-in development server by clicking "Start Debugging". However, when I deploy it to our testing server (Windows 2003 Server 64-bit running IIS in 32-bit mode), execution breaks when it reaches the code above, giving me the following message:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   CustomMembershipProvider.AttemptLogin() in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Josh\App_Code\CustomMembershipProvider.cs:1097
   ASP.global_asax.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Josh\Global.asax:14
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

How can I access the session state successfully in this situation? Why does it work locally and not on the server?

Comment: Why you don't call AttemptLogin() from Session_Start?

Comment: @Alex - I need this call to happen on ever request. It's due to some wonky session sharing code we have that ties together sessions for several different applications running on different platforms. The Application_AcquireRequestState method that kd7 suggested seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session Variables aren't available at Application_BeginRequest you should look later in the pipeline by handling the [Application_AcquireRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate.aspx) in your global.asax, I'm honestly puzzled why you don't get a null ref on your dev box.

Comment: Yup, that did it! It is bizarre that there was no issue when running it from within Visual Studio. I guess Microsoft's server implementations aren't 100% consistent. Sorry for the delay in testing/accepting your answer. I got pulled into another 'urgent' project right after asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the web.config file on the server and make sure sessionState mode is enabled

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" />
```